# Viewing G-suite devices login history

Tags: google-api, gmail, gmail-api, google-api-python-client, google-workspace

I'm trying to find anywhere in G-Suite API a way to view the data which I can find in 'My Account -> Sign-in & security -> Device activity & security events'.

I don't have any MDM system set up (which is the default) but on my web interface I can see my login history data (as you can see in the attached screenshots)- I would like to get that data through the G Suite API but cannot find it. Is there a way to view it?

Thanks

[example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBNtA.png)
[example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zm6kB.png)

Comment: Try checking the documentation about [Login Audit Activity Events](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/appendix/activity/login). For mobile, you can visit [Mobile Audit Activity Events](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/appendix/activity/mobile).

Comment: I tried those options - the query returns an empty answer even though there's data in the web ui